# Can I use named parameters in std::function template signature type argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

Can I legally use names for template parameters in `std::function` (or another similar construct)? E.g. given the code

```
std::function<int(int, int)> some_func;
```

Can I rewrite it in following way?

```
std::function<int(int begin, int end)> some_func;
```

It would be very nice, if it is standard compliant, because the type alone carries little information about the purpose of the parameter.

So far I've tested it in Visual Studio 2013 and it works. Edit: It works with gcc 4.8.1 too.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? If works, well ... then you can.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: It would only prove that his compiler accepts it, not that the standard allows it.

Comment: §8.3.5/11 [dcl.fct]
 "An identifier can optionally be provided as a parameter name;" `int (int, int)` is a function, so the clause applies here.

Comment: `int (*foo)(int begin, int end) = nullptr` basically.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, you're right, but that's not the question. He ask if he **can** and obviusly he did. If it is standar or not if a different question.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: Quotes from the question (emphasis by me): "Can I **legally** use […]", "[…] if it is **standard compliant,** […]" That makes it absolutely clear that the question is about what the standard allows.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you can provide the parameter name. From paragraph §8.3.5/11 of the C++11 Standard:

> An identifier can optionally be provided as a parameter name;

The same goes for pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member function type. Personally, I would use the identifier only if it expresses more clearly the intention of your code.

Answer (score 9):

For the language lawyers:

The grammar does allow this. Whether or not this is intentional is unclear to me. A *declarator* and an *abstract-declarator* differ in that the latter doesn't allow a name at the top level.

*declarator*:

- *ptr-declarator*
- *noptr-declarator* *parameters-and-qualifiers* *trailing-return-type*

*ptr-declarator*:

- *noptr-declarator*
- *ptr-operator* *ptr-declarator*

*noptr-declarator*:

- *declarator-id* *attribute-specifier-seq* (opt)
- *noptr-declarator* *parameters-and-qualifiers*
- *noptr-declarator* `[` *constant-expression* (opt) `]` *attribute-specifier-seq* (opt)
- `(` *ptr-declarator* `)`

Note that in a *declarator* you can have a *declarator-id*, that is, a name. Now consider the syntax of an *abstract-declarator*:

*abstract-declarator*:

- *ptr-abstract-declarator*
- *noptr-abstract-declarator* (opt) *parameters-and-qualifiers* *trailing-return-type*
- *abstract-pack-declarator*

*ptr-abstract-declarator*:

- *noptr-abstract-declarator*
- *ptr-operator* *ptr-abstract-declarator* (opt)

*noptr-abstract-declarator*:

- *noptr-abstract-declarator* (opt) *parameters-and-qualifiers*
- *noptr-abstract-declarator* (opt) `[` *constant-expression* (opt) `]` *attribute-specifier-seq* (opt)
- `(` *ptr-abstract-declarator* `)`

An *abstract-declarator* can't contain a *declarator-id* at top level. However, notice that the *parameters-and-qualifiers* that occurs in the production rules for *abstract-declarator* and *noptr-abstract-declarator* is the same as that in *declarator* and *noptr-declarator*. There is no special *abstract-parameters-and-qualifiers* to enforce not having a name within a parameter list that occurs in an *abstract-declarator*. So the grammar allows names to be specified for function parameters inside *abstract-declarators* even though the overall function type can't be given a name.